# beforeunload event not firing after page refresh on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, jquery-events

I'm trying to add a warning to a user if they are leaving the page without saving their changes, currently this works by setting the `isEdited` and `isSubmitButtonClicked` variables on certain events, 
Let's assume that `isEdited` is True and `isSubmitButtonClicked` is false.

This works for Chrome/Firefox in all cases yet in Safari it works the first time, wherein the alert shows up, I can click leave page and then navigate back to that same page try to make another change and leave the page and this time the alert does NOT show up.

This is only an issue for Safari, does anyone have any experience or ideas I can try?

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function (e) {
    if (isEdited && !isSubmitButtonClicked) {
        var confirmationMessage = 'test';
        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
        return confirmationMessage;
    }
    isSubmitButtonClicked = false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I seem to remember something about beforeunload that it doesn't fire unless the user clicks into the browser window first.